# Why is the Observable timer in Service reset everytime I route to different components?

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Service.ts**

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"}) 
export class MinuteCounter{ 
private timer$: Observable<number>; 
private sub$: Subscription;

constructor(){
    this.timer$ = timer(0, 60000);
}

public get timer(): Observable<number>{
    return this.timer$;
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
constructor(private minuteCounter : MinuteCounter){}
ngOnInit() { this.minuteCounter.timer.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**Component.html**

```
{{ minuteCounter.timer | async }}
```

I have minute counting Observable timer in Service file which constantly resets itself whenever I route to different component and come back. I thought data in Service are saved even though I move to different components? Basically I want the timer to stay constant and running in the background even when I'm on different components. And when i go back to this component, I would like to see the constant incremented timer.

I have done the Tour of Heroes Tutorial which shows me the example of using Service but I'm not sure why this isn't working.

I went through a lot of stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Have you tried to using `interval(60000).pipe(startWith(0))` instead of `timer(0, 60000)` ? I think the `interval` operator will continue emitting values until explicitly stopped.

Comment: long story short - it does not reset. Its just created everytime you subscribe to your pipe (create a distinct unique independent pipe with bran new timer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have only one service in all of your project, but because the actual observable is actually created when it's subscribed to, not when it's assigned an Observable, every time you unsubscribe and subscribe again it's creating a new one, to fix it you can simple use `share()`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, timer, tap, share } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MinuteCounterService {
  private timer$: Observable<number>;
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor');
    this.timer$ = timer(0, 5000).pipe(share());
    this.timer$.subscribe((v) =>
      console.log('MinuteCounterService.constructor', v)
    );
  }

  public get timer(): Observable<number> {
    return this.timer$.pipe(
      tap((v) => console.log('MinuteCounterService.timer', v))
    );
  }
}
```

full working exam in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtf1dk)

you can remove the `share()` and navigate to the other component to see that the values in the `MinuteCounterService.constructor` and `MinuteCounterService.timer` are not synced, while it's for sure the same object as `constructor` was logged only once

Comment: I whink `share()` is more suitable so every events will happen at once, and not additionally right after every subscription (after first emission ofc)

Comment: @Antoniossss you are right, I didn't pay much attention and just picked `shareReply` since I use it more often in my day2day work, modified the solution accordingly, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Thank you so much!
This actually fixed it. I didn't know you had to subscribe within the Service!

Comment: @YoungKim if my fix solve your problem please mark it as accepted